# Run docker-compose commands on project without specifying config files

Tags: docker-compose, command-line-interface

I have a docker-compose project which uses inheritance, and as such has multiple yaml files I have to specify via `-f` options whenever I run a command. However, I also supply a project name with `-p`.

As it stands right now, every time I want to run a command on the project, I have to add all the config files (and in the right order) for every command, and I have to be in the directory where the files are or specify the full path to each. Since I deploy using gitlab, the path changes with every deployment, which means I have to go look it up on gitlab before being able to run commands there.

For example:

1. Go to deployment job, look up location of the pulled repository.
2. Strip .git from it.
3. `cd` to path.
4. Type `docker-compose -p my_project_name -f docker-compose.base.yaml -f docker-compose.something.yaml -f docker-compose.other.yaml down`
5. Repeat 4 in all its lengthy ugliness for every additional command I want to execute.

This is extremely unwieldy.

Since the project has an associated project name, is there a way I can use it to call commands on it without having to specify the config files, and without having to navigate to the project's directory? If not, is there any other way?